# Yellow Marks on all references

Tags: c#, visual-studio

Have a solution, call is Solution_A which contains 16 projects.  They all work correctly.   Created a second solution, Solution_B.   In Solution_B added an existing project from Solution_A.   When I look at the references in Solution_B all references have a yellow marking.   They do not have a path associated with any of them.  This includes the System.dll reference.  I have added new projects to Solution_B and they are fine regards to the references.   I have tried to add the System.dll manually and it ends up with the same issue.

I have double and triple checked the .NET Framework is the same.

If I build the solution (or the project) I do receive an error about missing nuGet packages.  In my thinking this does not explain why System.dll is causing the warning.

Any suggestions on how to correct this issue? or a way to receive more information on why this is occurring?

Using VS 2019.

Thanks for the assistance.
Duane

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Adding a ProjectReference to a project that is not in the same solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11601950/adding-a-projectreference-to-a-project-that-is-not-in-the-same-solution)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Found the solution to my issue.  Typically when I start VS it's started as run as Administrator.  One time I started it regular, not as run as administrator.   The reference list was correct.  The project built as expected.  Now when I run it as administrator all is correct.

I cannot explain this but I will not argue with success.

Comment: I am glad to hear that your problem has been solved, you can click '✔' to mark your reply as an answer. It will also help others to solve the similar issue.